# How to access data from a 'Page' on Facebook in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am new to iOS development and I have to fetch the data from a 'Page' on facebook. By 'Page' I mean a page that we generally like on Facebook and is owned by a brand or celebrity.

I would also want to know that since these pages are already public pages, do I need to take permission from the owner to access data on that 'Page' in my app?

Thanks.

Comment: Not all pages are public

Answer (score 0):

What data do you mean photos, links, posts,...?
If you want access to the feed try this:

```
/* make the API call */
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/{page-id}/feed" 
                  parameters:nil 
                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                  completionHandler:^(
                      FBRequestConnection *connection,
                      id result,
                      NSError *error
                  ) {
                      /* handle the result */
                  }];
```

If you want photos try replacing /feed with /photos.

This is what I can find about the permissions:

**Permissions**

- An access token is required to view publicly shared posts.
- A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person.
- A page access token is required to retrieve any other posts.